# Launch a command shell from a console application run via Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, windows, shell, scheduled-tasks

I have a Windows console application that is launched via a schedule setup in Task Scheduler.  This console application, as part of its normal runtime, will launch a command prompt in order to run a java program.  No, I have no control over the design of the Java program.  It was supplied to me as is and I have no rights or access to make changes to it.  I also cannot implement it in another language.  I must use what was given to me.

At any rate, when my console application tries to run the command prompt it will work just fine if I'm launching the application manually.  However, when I try it as an action within Task Scheduler, my console application will start and run as expected until it needs to launch the command prompt.  At this point, the console application exits.  No error message or code is provided.

How do I get the command prompt window to start as a new window from within my console application when no one is logged into the server?

Thanks for any hints or suggestions you can provide.

*** UPDATE ***

Here is the code snippet that launches the program from within my console application:

```
string parameter_save_path = @"C:\output\folder"
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo start_info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
start_info.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\mtselect-client";
start_info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
start_info.Arguments = "/C run.bat \"" + parameter_save_path + "\"";
process.StartInfo = start_info;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

The run.bat is what launches the java program.

Comment: Could you share some code? How are you currently launching the java program within your commandline app?

Comment: Sorry about that.  Code snippet is now part of the original post.

Comment: Bummer.  I guess no one has a clue on how to do this.  I guess I'll try splitting the program into two parts and adding three actions to my task.  This way, the java program will be run directly by the task scheduler rather than called by the program.  Gotta be a better way to do this, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's too late for this message, but...

Maybe in your batch file you are running your java application with something like: java -jar ApplicationName

First I would do should be comment out the "@echo off" from the batch file, next trace out the batch lines with one echo "x" (being x a natural number starting from 1 and increasing by 1 in each ocurrence). Next I will add a line with java -version, and so I will be sure java app is installed and accesible.

Maybe java needs be ran by an authenticated user and so have java_home defined. Maybe the application needs some JVM parameters like memory size, etc.

Have good luck, tell me and I will try to help